# How to express double orthogonal complement?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ be a Hilbert space and $U \subseteq V$. Then $U^\perp = \{\mathbf{v} \in V|\forall \mathbf{u} \in U, \langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle = 0 \}$.

My question is, how do you express $\left(U^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}$? I attempted to simply chain two definitions together. $\left(U^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}
     = \{\mathbf{w} \in V|\forall \mathbf{v} \in V,
      \forall \mathbf{u} \in U,
      \langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle = 0|
      \langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w} \rangle = 0\}$, but I don't think that is valid.

Comment: Isn't one implication of the fundamental theorem of linear algebra that the complement of the complement of S is S itself?

Comment: Sorry for potentially missing the point but isn't the double orthogonal complement the original subspace?

Comment: @autolatry For finite dimensional vector spaces, the double orthogonal complement is indeed the original. This is no-longer true for infinite dimensional spaces (which is the standard context for Hilbert spaces).

Comment: @EuYu Ah, I see. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say whether your expression is valid.  However, it is certainly unclear since you include more than one $\mid$ in your set definition.  I would write something like this:
$$
\newcommand{\ip}[1]{\langle#1 \rangle}
(U^\perp)^\perp = 
\{w \in V: v \in U^\perp \implies \ip{v,w} = 0\}\\
= \{w \in V: (\forall u \in U, \ip{v,u} = 0) \implies \ip{v,w} = 0\}
$$
That being said, even this isn't the *simplest* expression for $(U^\perp)^\perp$.  We can show that, in general, $(U^\perp)^\perp = \overline{U}$.